# Fix undefined, Client and Server side

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I did the json HTML which pulls up the json object or list. You can tell me what sort of json it is. 
Using http://servername:5018/hoteldata which pulls up this.  This is an example of what should pull up in myphpadmin. Using Get command from the route server.

```
    [
  {
    "firstname": "Bill", 
    "lastname": "Richson", 
    "numberofguest": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Jane", 
    "lastname": "Freda", 
    "numberofguest": "3"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Mark", 
    "lastname": "Harrison", 
    "numberofguest": "7"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Chris", 
    "lastname": "Asher", 
    "numberofguest": "4"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Ruth", 
    "lastname": "King", 
    "numberofguest": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Andy", 
    "lastname": "Webb", 
    "numberofguest": "5"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Mary ", 
    "lastname": "Gardner", 
    "numberofguest": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Mark", 
    "lastname": "Harrison", 
    "numberofguest": "7"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Anna ", 
    "lastname": "Mitchell", 
    "numberofguest": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Karl", 
    "lastname": "Robertson", 
    "numberofguest": "3"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Liam", 
    "lastname": "Barnard", 
    "numberofguest": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Tommy", 
    "lastname": "McCree", 
    "numberofguest": "4"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Peter", 
    "lastname": "Root", 
    "numberofguest": "6"
  }, 
  {
    "firstname": "Test", 
    "lastname": "Guest", 
    "numberofguest": "1"
  }
]
```

I want to use the get in the HTML and it just came up undefined. I have used the HTML coding with Java which has a button.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    function getIp() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var output = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("hoteldata").innerHTML = output.hoteldata;
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://cs2s.yorkdc.net:5018/hoteldata", true);
        xhttp.send();
    } 
</script>


<body>
<p id="hoteldata"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="getIp()">Click me to get your ip address.</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The response from your server is not wrapped into an object with the property `hoteldata`. so you would use the output data directly. maybe rename it to hoteldata.

Often people ask how to stringify object to html or xml.
I like this simple function.

```js
function objectToHTML(o){
    if(Array.isArray(o)){return o.map(objectToHTML).join('')}
    if(!o)return '';
    var r = '<ul class="object">';
    Object.keys(o).forEach(key=>{
        if(typeof o[key] === 'object'){
            r += objectToHTML(o[key]);

        } else if(typeof o[key] === 'string' || typeof o[key] === 'number'){
            r+='<li>'+
                '<b>'+key+'</b>'+
                '<div>'+escape(o[key].toString())+'</div>'+
                '</li>';
        }
    });
    return r+ '</ul>'
}
```

as this function return a string, you can use it like:

```js
  document.getElementById("hoteldata").innerHTML = objectToHTML(output);
```

feel free to change the class names or tags, you can even add more structure to it, based on some extra information to pass in. have fun with this function